# How to use Mongo $pop?

Tags: mongodb

I am able to `$push` an object onto a Mongo array as follows:

```
db.foo.update({},{$push:{bar:3}})
```

But I can't find a syntax that will allow me to `$pop` the last item from the list.

I've tried things like:

```
db.foo.find({$pop:{bar:1}})
```

which does nothing. I've also tried

```
db.foo.find({id:23},{$pop:{bar:1}})
```

which outputs:

```
error: { "$err" : "Unsupported projection option: bar", "code" : 13097 }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$pop` exists and works almost like you've got it there, but you need to find some elements first!

```
db.foo.update({ _id: someId }, { $pop: { bar:1 } });
```

See [the docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24pop).

Comment: I've updated my question. I had tried that sort of thing, but I get an error.

Comment: OK, that works ... I guess I just expected to receive the value. I wanted to obtain that last element in the list. Can `$pop` help with that?

Comment: Hmm, not really unfortunately. Check out the [docs for advanced querying](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries) for the possibilities.